# Footer does not stick to the bottom even when it is set to position: absolute;

Tags: html, css

I am creating a footer for my site and I wanted the footer to be fixed at the bottom. But when I scroll down, this won't go along with the document. It stays at the bottom of the page always. I have initialized the footer to position: absolute, and also added bottom: 0 of my CSS code. But it still stuck in the middle of the page. How can I resolve this everyone?

```css
.footer {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  .upper-footer,
  .lower-footer {
    padding: 10px 0 33px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .upper-footer {
    background: #252525;
    .upper-footer-links {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      margin: 3px -3px;
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      .span {
        position: inherit;
        right: -1px;
        color: #7b7b7b;
      }
    }
  }
  .lower-footer {
    background: #3c3c3c;
    height: 74px;
    .footer-information {
      float: left;
      width: 458px;
      p {
        line-height: 23px;
        margin: 15px 0;
        color: #9b9b9b;
      }
    }
    .footer-sns-links {
      float: right;
      padding: 28px 0;
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
        li {
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid #686868;
          padding: 8px;
          &:hover {
            background-color: #373737;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="upper-footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="upper-footer-links">
        <a href="#">개인정보처리방침</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
        <a href="#">이메일무단수집거부</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
        <a href="#">사이트맵</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
        <a href="#">찾아오시는 길</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower-footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="footer-information">
        <p class="footer-info">02841 서울특별시 성북구 안암로 145 크림슨창업지원단 &nbsp;|&nbsp; TEL : 02.3290.4810 &nbsp;|&nbsp; E-MAIL : startup@korea.ac.kr<br>COPYRIGHT(C)2018 KOREA UNIVERSITY. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-sns-links">
        <ul>
          <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_02.png"></li>
          <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_03.png"></li>
          <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_01.png"></li>
          <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_04.png"></li>
          <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_05.png"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, my footer has two different footers, the upper footer and the lower footer and both footers are inside a div called ".footer"

Comment: you can take it help from here [link](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `position: relative;` on a parent div or to the `body`  tag wich I did. This will then position it to the bottom of the page becuase the `body` tag spans the entire document.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.lorem {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.footer {
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
color: white;

    .upper-footer, .lower-footer {
        padding: 10px 0 33px 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .upper-footer {
        background: #252525;
            .upper-footer-links {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                margin: 3px -3px;
                    a {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: #ffffff;
                    }
                    .span {
                            position: inherit;
                            right: -1px;
                            color: #7b7b7b;
                        }
            }
    }
    .lower-footer {
        background: #3c3c3c;
        height: 74px;
            .footer-information {
                float: left;
                width: 458px;
                p {
                    line-height: 23px;
                    margin: 15px 0;
                    color: #9b9b9b;
                }

            }
            .footer-sns-links {
                float: right;
                padding: 28px 0;
                    ul {
                        list-style: none;
                        display: inline;

                            li {
                                display: inline-block;
                                border: 1px solid #686868;
                                padding: 8px;
                                &:hover {
                                    background-color: #373737;
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed.

Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Pretium lectus quam id leo in. Diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis.

Vitae congue eu consequat ac. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. In egestas erat imperdiet sed. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra.

Quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Pretium lectus quam id leo. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas. Odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus.</div>
<div class="footer">
  
        <div class="upper-footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="upper-footer-links">
                    <a href="#">개인정보처리방침</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#">이메일무단수집거부</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#">사이트맵</a>&nbsp; <span>|</span> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#">찾아오시는 길</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lower-footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="footer-information">
                    <p class="footer-info">02841 서울특별시 성북구 안암로 145 크림슨창업지원단 &nbsp;|&nbsp; TEL : 02.3290.4810 &nbsp;|&nbsp; E-MAIL : startup@korea.ac.kr<br>COPYRIGHT(C)2018 KOREA UNIVERSITY. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-sns-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_02.png"></li>
                            <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_03.png"></li>
                            <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_01.png"></li>
                            <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_04.png"></li>
                            <li><img href="#" src="images/icon/icon_ss_05.png"></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Ah okay have you added a ```position: relative``` to the ```body``` tag?

Comment: yup. but the footer is still at the middle of the page. could this be because of my other divs? because i have one dive that has a height of 1094 px since the contents of the page is not yet added to the page itself. So i made a dummy div which is empty and added a height to it.

Comment: Ahh great please click the answered checkbox on my answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the footer property

```
position : fixed
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

and maybe your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full-width footer at bottom of page try this

```
{
position : absolute
left: 0;
right : 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

And you want the full-width footer to slide along the page

```
{
position : fixed
left: 0;
right : 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Happy coding